# Powershell keylogger skips characters if I write quickly

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell keylogger that works almost perfectly, it captures all characters, the clipboard, if I write slowly it works fine, but if I write quickly it skips characters. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Where is the code ? ...

Comment: You probably can't if powershell is too slow to capture your fast typing. You need to look for an alternative solution.

Comment: Thanks David, I struggled to make a FUD keylogger and would like to correct this error. Could it be a memory problem?